# How to trigger a computed property using the global ember-data store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

```
App.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    available: function() {
        var all = this.store.all('bar');
    }.property()
});
```

When another model "bar" is added to the global ember-data store, how can I trigger the property to recalculate?

I'm using the latest stable ember 1.1.2 and ember-data 1.0 beta 3

Answer (score 1):

All is an active filter, meaning it should update on it's own.  Additionally calling all multiple times will return the same 'filtered' array.  If you need a different computed property to depend on it you can use each:

```
App.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    available: function() {
        return this.store.all('bar');
    }.property(),

    someTriggerProperty: function(){

    }.property('available.@each')
});
```

I'm low on sleep so maybe I'm missing something, or failing to explain something correctly.  Here's an example, could you show me a portion I'm thinking of incorrectly:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OLaYOPI/1/edit

Comment: It doesn't appear to update on it's own. I do a this.store.all('bar').clear() and then re-populate it -this computed property never fires again unless I refresh the browser manually (anything I might be doing wrong)?

Comment: Which computed property? available, or someTriggerProperty?

Comment: just the store itself -when I clear it or add to it I don't know how to trip the computed property (trigger won't work unless I can trip when the store is updated)

Comment: Check out the updated response, fill me in on what I'm missing.